# form submit doesn't callback

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a form with standard submit.

```
var formDettaglio = new Ext.form.FormPanel({

    title: 'Dettaglio richiesta',
    renderTo: 'divDettaglio',
    url: '/supporto/gestioneDettaglio',
    standardSubmit: true,
    width: '100%',
    forceFit: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    defaults: {
        border: false
    },
    margin: '0 0 15 0',
    items: [{
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            margin: '0 10 5 10',
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    fieldLabel: 'Prodotto/Servizio',
                    labelWidth: 100,
                    width: 450,
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    name: 'cbAssets',
                    store: storeAssets,
                    displayField: 'valore',
                    valueField: 'codice'
                }, {
                    flex: 1,
                    xtype: 'label',
                    text: ' '
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Data chiusura prev.',
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    labelWidth: 120,
                    width: 250,
                    name: 'textDataPrevista',
                    readOnly: true
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Stato',
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    labelWidth: 50,
                    width: 150,
                    name: 'textStato'
                }
            ]
        }, {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            fieldLabel: 'Motivo richiesta',
            labelWidth: 100,
            height: 150,
            margin: '0 10 5 10',
            name: 'textMotivo'
        }
    ],
    dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            padding: '2 0 2 0',
            dock: 'bottom',
            ui: 'footer',
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'tbfill'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Salva',
                    style: "width:100px; height:25px;",
                    handler: function () {
                        if (formDettaglio.getForm().isValid()) {
                            formDettaglio.getForm().submit({
                                params: {
                                    azione: 'SALVA'
                                },
                                success: function (form, action) {
                                    alert('ok');
                                },
                                failure: function (form, action) {
                                    alert('ko');
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert('Errore!');
                        }
                    }]
            }]
    });
```

My called function, `/supporto/gestioneDettaglio`, send a json response 
`{"success":true}`

But my success function doesn't start. I tried also with breakpoint on firebug: no way.
I get back an empty page with exactly the phrase... `{"success":true}`

What am I doing wrong? I send JSON like any other response in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `standardSubmit` set to true.  If you want to do an ajax submission with the callback functionality you need to set the `standardSubmit` property to false.

Comment: Setting standardSubmit: false, i get correct server response. But now, i can't understand why my params: {azione: 'SALVA'}, is not sent to server?!!? Also tried with Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: '/supporto/gestioneDettaglio',
   params: {azione: 'SALVA'},
   form: 'formDettaglio',
   method:'POST',
   success: function(response, opts) {
    alert("successfull");
   },
   failure:function(res,opt) {
    alert("request failed");
   }
  });
Same problem: params doesn't works.
Any suggest??? Thanks

Comment: Adding to my Ext.Ajax.request, as above, the line
jsonData: { },
now params are correctly sent to my server.
Anyone can explain this? I'd like to understand this case... Thanks

Comment: Well.  You can use your original example with standardSubmit set to false and then just include a hidden field on your form with the name:azione and value:'SALVA' and it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Solved with "standardSubmit:false"
On submit click, I called

```
Ext.Ajax.request({ url: '/supporto/gestioneDettaglio', 
    params: {azione: 'SALVA'},
    jsonData: { }, 
    form: 'formDettaglio', 
    method:'POST', 
    success: function(response, opts) { alert("successfull"); }, 
    failure:function(res,opt) { alert("request failed"); }
});
```

I don't understand why the Ajax request, without "jsonData: { },", didn't pass parameters... But it's ok.
Thanks!